# kaggle api not showing everything

Tags: kaggle

!kaggle competitions files -c planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space

I ran the code in above, but it does not show me all the files. It only shows:

```
!kaggle competitions files -c planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space

Warning: Looks like you're using an outdated API Version, please consider updating (server 1.5.6 / 

client 1.5.4)
name                                                size  creationDate         
-------------------------------------------------  -----  -------------------  
train_v2.csv/train_v2.csv                            1MB  2019-12-15 22:14:13  
sample_submission_v2.csv/sample_submission_v2.csv    3MB  2019-12-15 22:14:13  
test_v2_file_mapping.csv/test_v2_file_mapping.csv  600KB  2019-12-15 22:14:13  
Kaggle-planet-test-tif.torrent                       2MB  2019-12-15 22:14:13  
Kaggle-planet-train-tif.torrent                      1MB  2019-12-15 22:14:13
```

It should show this, I can not download the train jpg tar file: [all file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMlab.png)
[https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space/data][2]

My colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19hLo3NN_NY6tbXjEpWOI5y_bEVujikTF

Comment: "I ran the code in above"...but there's no code.  Also you're clearly getting a warning from the server regarding the outdated API you're using, perhaps you should update .

Comment: this code: !kaggle competitions files -c planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space

Comment: I tried everything to upgrade it in colab, everything failed(my Kaggle API is 1.5.4).

Comment: My colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19hLo3NN_NY6tbXjEpWOI5y_bEVujikTF

Comment: I am also facing same error (upgraged to 1.5.4, still the error persists). Did you try following command? !kaggle --version

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was not a version. The problem was the kaggle uploader has changed the file location. Thus, I solved the issue by uploading the ~1GB data set to the google drive and mount the data to Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Uw05Af4DyelmC59LTq8QCByn1vbw50e  If you still have a problem, please send me an email to contact me: 777JonathanSum@gmail.com.